# Get count from Powershell Group-Object

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get some stats about our code. This works fine for one module:

```
function countTestCases($path=$pwd) {
   Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Include *.java | Where-Object {-not $_.PSIsContainer } |     Select-String "extends ComponentTestCase", "extends DatabaseDependentTestcase" | Group-Object Pattern | Select-Object Count
}
```

but I want run this across all modules to get a CSV output like this:

```
module,#ComponentTestCase,#DatabaseDependantTestCase
module1,20,30
module2,12,1
```

unfortunately, if I add

```
| Select-Obejct Count
```

it doesn't work (although Name does). not sure how to get around this without writing too much code...

Answer (score 0):

It works (at least for me).  Is it perhaps because this data is right aligned and you don't notice it on the far right side of your console?  Also, rather than use select, you can pick off "just" the property value with a `Foreach` cmdlet e.g.:

```
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Filter *.java | Where {!$_.PSIsContainer } |
 Select-String "extends ComponentTestCase","extends DatabaseDependentTestcase" | 
 Group-Object Pattern | Foreach {$_.Count}
```

`Select-Object` creates a whole new object to contain just the properties you selected from the incoming object so a lot of the time it is overkill.  Also, I would recommend using the `Filter` parameter on `Get-ChildItem` over `Include` as `Fiter` is quite a bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt simpler find a way.. but this seems to works

```
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Include *.cs | Select-String "int", "string" | Group-Object Pattern -AsHashTable | foreach {
    new-object psobject -Property @{
        int = $_['int'].Count;
        string = $_['string'].Count;
        module = 'mymodulename'}
    } | select module, int, string
```

The output looks like

```
module                                            int                    string
------                                            ---                    ------
mymodulename                                       19                        78
```

I'm using string and int as my patterns, but you'll have to replace it for yours

Comment: You typically do not have to quote string args (unless you have spaces) e.g.: `... | Select-String int,string` works just as well.  Also, you can access the hashtable values by property name syntax: `int = $_.int.count`.

Comment: huppy_doodoo had spaces in his patterns, i put the quotes just in case :)